# How to print texts between scanner next?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and having trouble using Scanner to take several inputs with print texts in between. The following code will not print the texts but will take inputs only. Please help!

```
private static void createNewMochaDrink() {

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please select which Mocha you would like");
   System.out.println("1. White Chocolate Mocha\n2. Dark Chocolate Mocha\n3. Peppermint Mocha");
   int choice = scan.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter Milk amount: ");
   double milkAmount = scan.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Enter Espresso Shot: ");
   double espressoShot = scan.nextDouble();
   scan.nextLine();
   System.out.print("Enter Chocolate Type: ");
   String chocoType = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all I would switch to `System.out.println(...)` instead of `print`. It adds a carriage return and makes your printed statements easier to read.

Secondly, if what you want to do is print what the user has just typed in, then you need to add:

```
private static void createNewMochaDrink() {

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Please select which Mocha you would like");
       System.out.println("1. White Chocolate Mocha\n2. Dark Chocolate Mocha\n3. Peppermint Mocha");
       int choice = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter Milk amount: ");
       double milkAmount = scan.nextDouble();
       System.out.print("Enter Espresso Shot: ");
       double espressoShot = scan.nextDouble();
       scan.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Enter Chocolate Type: ");
       String chocoType = scan.nextLine();
       
       System.out.println("You selected: "+choice+" and "+
                          milkAmount+" milk and "+espressoShot+" espresso shots and "+
                          chocoType+" chocolate type");
}
```

And that will do the trick.

Here's the result in Eclipse's console

[image: Results in Eclipse]